# Nginx php-fpm header

Tags: nginx, php

Всем привет.

Ребят, подскажите, как настроить nginx, чтобы php файл отдавал, к примеру,
`header('Redirect: http://mysite');`.

У меня в php файле стоит проверка, авторизован пользователь или нет, и если да, то редирект на главную `header('Redirect: http://mysite');`, но он не срабатывает при Nginx php-fpm, а на apache все good.

Я не знаю, как сделать, уже 3 часа мучаюсь!

php5.3, Nginx 1.6.2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, тему можно закрывать, просто с rewrite чуть начудил, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

- До объявления заголовков не должно быть никакого вывода (вёрстки, текста):

Как неправильно:

```
<html>
<?php
  header("Location: http://mysite");
?>
</html>
```

Как правильно:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://mysite");
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

- Перед `<?php` не должно быть пробельных символов.
- Возможно, проблема в том, что файлы скрипта сохранены с [BOM-маркером](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). 
  **Решение**: в редакторе/IDE сохранить в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Чем Вас не устраивает

```
header('Location: http://mysite') ??
```

Comment: Он неработает на Nginx php-fpm! В том то и дело.